# Searching for ads asqlcmd utility

Tags: advantage-database-server

I'm using Advantage Database Server v10.10.0.6
I know there is a commandline utility known as ASQLCMD.
It wasn't installed with the initial installation (1-1-2013)

Can anybody tell me where to find it?

Reason: I desperately need it for offline queries.

Tia

Pim

Comment: You should better ask this question here: http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/forum/

Answer (score 1):

At least for ADS 11 it is part of the ARC32-Installation and can be found in the same folder as arc32.exe.

There is an overview with all download links here:

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=31